# Angular stub service with static properties

Tags: angular, unit-testing, static, karma-runner

I've a service which is called with `APP_INITIALIZE` to make some steps to assign it's property a value. This property is static and my another service relies on it. How do I stub this service with static value?

The trick is that `provide` isn't working in that case since it's being used from import. I don't want to use a real initialize service since it may break in case there is no config file and I don't want to break tests of services which rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this service in another test you would in it's TestBed declare

`{provide: APP_INITIALIZE, useClass: initializeStub}`

where initializeStub is something like :

```
export class intializeStub extends APP_INITIALIZE {
blah() {
  return 'hi';
}}
```